# Compass Lucene indexing PhantomReadLock error

Tags: mysql, tomcat, lucene, compass-lucene

I'm using MySQL to store Compass indexes, with Tomcat on RHEL, but when I shut down Tomcat and restart my indexing process, this error is thrown while indexing, and indexing fails:

> PhantomReadLock  unable to obtain lock, write.lock/customer-index

Maybe because I shut down Tomcat, this error occurs in Compass?  After much Googling around, I found that I need to manually delete the write.lock file, but I couldn't find the lock file anywhere in my Tomcat temp folder.  I did get a record with write.lock in my customer-index table in MySQL, so I deleted that row and Compass started indexing properly and the PhantomReadLock error no longer occurs.

I just want to clarify -- is this the correct way to solve this write.lock issue or do I need to do something else to delete the lock while shutting down Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem using Tomcat and I found this article : http://docs.ngdata.com/daisy-kb/443-daisy.html.

What I learned is that if you just kill Tomcat when you shut it down (in eclipse you can do it "properly" or not), *write.lock* remains there, whereas if you shut it down using the shutdown.sh/bat script, the file is deleted and next restart is all clean.

Even though this is an old question, I hope it helps anyone finding it by chance.